# how add meta description in tpl file

Tags: smarty, meta

I need to add meta description from content

I have main.tpl and there is

```html
<meta name="author" content="Kuzdrowiu.pl">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./w3css.css">
    <title>{$tresc.title} | Medycyna Naturalna</title>
```

The content is taken from this code:

```html
<div id="content_middle">{include file="$content"}</div>
```

By entering the code below I can call the meta description but only with the html code. How can I do it differently? I've been sitting here for 3 days and nothing is working properly.

```html
<meta name="description" content='{$tresc.content}'>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if-else condition help you:

> `{if $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI eq '/URL-1'}`
>
> `<meta name='description' content='YOUR-DESCRIPTION-1'>`
>
> `{elseif $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI eq '/URL-2'}`
>
> `<meta name='description' content='YOUR-DESCRIPTION-2'>`
>
> `{/if}`